# How to prove by mathematical induction that $(y-x)x^n \leq \frac{y^{n+1}-x^{n+1}}{n+1} \leq (y-x)y^n$?

Tags: inequality, induction

> Prove by induction that: 
>   $$(y-x)x^n \leq \frac{y^{n+1}-x^{n+1}}{n+1} \leq (y-x)y^n\ .
> $$

---

As a hint, the professor told us to use the following expression that we had previously proven: 
$$\sum_{i=0}^n{x^i}= \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}
$$

I already tried several things, but I can’t manage to get to the solution.

Comment: I suppose you assume that $y>x$?

Comment: It definitely holds for $n=0$.

Comment: Yes sorry. It’s for 0<x<y

Comment: And what exactly have you tried?

Comment: Were you really told to use induction *and* to use the result you had previously proved (presumably by using induction)? I can see no need to use both. You could use induction, but this would probably duplicate the proof of the previous result. You can use the previous result directly (i.e. without using induction again) by observing that if $x < 1$, then the left hand side is less than $n+1$ and greater than $(n+1)x^n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quit sure how to use the hint given by the professor. But here's one way to do this:

Recall that $$(y^{n+1}-x^{n+1}) = (y-x)(y^n+y^{n-1}x+....+yx^{n-1}+x^{n})$$

Now assuming that $x<y$ you can replace all the $y$'s with $x$'s in the second multiple<sup>1</sup> and get that $$y^{n+1}-x^{n+1} \geq (y-x) (n+1)x^n$$ Divide by $n+1$ and you get the first inequality. For the other one replace the $x$'s with $y$'s.

---

<sup>1.</sup><sup>**Edit** It's possible that you need to prove this part by induction. That is, prove by induction that $$(n+1)x^n \leq y^n+y^{n-1}x+...+yx^{n-1}+x^n$$</sup>

Comment: Thanks!! I’ll try that